I have a disconnect between the data folder database name and the name which shows up in the database list
So this is what it looks like in PHPMyAdmin and if I Show Databases; in the client.
When I click on it I get the no databse selected...
when doing a mysql_upgrade I also get

mariadb-check: Got error: 1102: Incorrect database name
'#mysql50#veterans.bkup.july29' when selecting the database

there is a folder in the /var/mysql folder with the title minus the hashtage

